# Javascript - Why does it only occur och first div and not on the second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know javascript really but have taken one witch works but it only works once on the first div on every page.

Look at this fiddle. [https://jsfiddle.net/Lr0g8snL/1/]

```
<div id="div4">jQuery Click to Toggle</div>
```

jQuery Click to Toggle

I you click the first div, it toggles the background on/off.

I've added the #div4 "jQuery Click to Toggle" twice and it only works on the first one.

How do i get it to work on all divs called #div4?

Thank you!

Comment: add all relevant code to OP instead of adding a link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ka7hfL66/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element should have a unique `ID`, use a class selector instead, or give them different `IDs` and select them then.

```
<div class="div4">jQuery Click to Toggle</div>

$(".div4").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('back-red');
});
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr0g8snL/2/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, good to know about the ID/Class difference there.